# SignalR Persistent Connection in a coded Webtest

Tags: signalr, webtest, persistent-connection

I have the following code in a console app:

```
var connection = new Connection("http://localhost/xxx/signalr");
connection.Error += ex =>
{
    string msg = string.Format("***SignalR Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(msg);
};
connection.Received += data =>
{
    string msg = string.Format("***SignalR Received: {0}", data);                    
    Debug.WriteLine(msg);
};
connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("***SignalR Failed to start: {0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
        Debug.WriteLine(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        string msg = string.Format("***SignalR Started: {0}", connection.ConnectionId);
        Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        connection.Send("Hello");
    }
});
```

Debugging the server, I can see the `OnConnected` and `OnReceived` are called.
If I place the same code in a coded WebTest, the `OnConnected` on the server is called, but the `connection.Send` is not received on the server.

Q: Is it possible to use the SignalR .Net Client in a WebTest?

Q: What is the best way to use a SignalR Persistent Connection in a WebTest?

Thanks